finite Fourier transform of PDEs
give me any 2 question for solving 1 diminsional finite Fourier transform and multidimensioal finite Fourier transform (2 or 3 dim) ,
2 questions of Fourier transform of higher order PDES and
2 questions  Fourier and Laplace transform for IVPs
2 questions for finite Laplace (2 ODEs and 2 PDEs)

Welcome to MSE. That question is off-topic here.
